# Unable to start jenkins on redhat

Tags: linux, jenkins, redhat

I dowloaded and installed jenkins with the following commands on redhat
(3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

```
sudo wget  https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins-2.32.2-1.1.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh jenkins-2.32.2-1.1.noarch.rpm
```

And I started jenkins with the command

```
sudo service jenkins start
```

I got the output

```
Starting jenkins (via systemctl):                          [  OK  ]
```

But jenkins is not running.
I tried ps ax | grep -i jenkins and no process named jenkins is running.
I tried `service --status-all` and i can't see jenkins.
I tried to access ip:8080 which is also not showing anything.
But with `systemctl status jenkins.service` I can see that it started

```
  ● jenkins.service - LSB: Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2017-02-10 16:07:42 EST; 2min 7s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 16649 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16672 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 10 16:07:42 AWSINTDEV11.equinoxfitness.com systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Jenkins Continuous Integration Server...
Feb 10 16:07:42 AWSINTDEV11.equinoxfitness.com runuser[16673]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Feb 10 16:07:42 AWSINTDEV11.equinoxfitness.com jenkins[16672]: Starting Jenkins [  OK  ]
Feb 10 16:07:42 AWSINTDEV11.equinoxfitness.com systemd[1]: Started LSB: Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
```

Comment: Have you checked the Jenkins log, ` /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`?

Comment: Thanks.I found the error in /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log. It didn't have permission for /var/libs/jenkins.I fixed it.Working now.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference and those who doesn't bother to read the comments. Besides checking the system logs you should check the Jenkins log, which on most *nix systems is located in `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`. In this case it was insufficient permissions to `/var/libs/jenkins`.

BTW, If you can't find any errors in that log either, then you probably have some sort of ip-table issue where the Jenkins server can't be accessed from the outside.